# How does joomla breadcrumbs work internally?

Tags: joomla, navigation, joomla1.5, adsense, breadcrumbs

I've already gone thru: http://docs.joomla.org/How_to_add_breadcrumbs
and http://api.joomla.org/Joomla-Framework/Application/JPathway.html
but they don't help.

I have not found any more info in any books or internet.

My website   has 1000's of pages generated thru script.
I want to generate breadcrumb navigation for the pages.
Google has refused me Adsense account due to this lack of navigation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure what else there is to explain. Joomla stores breadcrumbs in the $pathway object. A components adds items to that object using 2 parameters, name and link.

You call the object with:

```
$pathway   =& $mainframe->getPathway();
```

Then you add to it with:

```
$pathway->addItem('name of item', 'link to item');
```

Then you add the breadcrumb module in the module manager. There is no more too it, what else would you need?

Comment: well I've found it. Actually it's not straightforward as you say. I had to debug the whole code.

Answer (score 1):

The breadcrumb is generally updated by the component that is being called.

```
$pathway =& $mainframe->getPathway();
```

And then

```
$pathway->addItem($membership->name, JRoute::_('index.php?option=com_rsmembership&view=membership&cid='.$membership->id.':'.JFilterOutput::stringURLSafe($membership->name) . "&Itemid=" . $itemid));
```

The above is an example from rsmembership

Essentially the breadcrumb is maintained (or stored) by Joomla, and added to by the components.

Comment: Thanks but it's quite limited answer. Also I hope somebody helps me answer query to help me understand this topic:http://forum.joomla.org/viewtopic.php?f=431&t=600704. On the whole net I've been able to find only two similar lines of code for breadcrumb generation. Little more is there in ebook Mastering Joomla. Still many thing aren't clear.